# Elmah giving NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, elmah

When I execute this line of code

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);
```

I get the following error

[image]

With the following stack trace...

```
       at Elmah.Error..ctor(Exception e, HttpContext context)
   at Elmah.ErrorMailModule.OnError(Exception e, HttpContext context)
   at Elmah.ErrorMailModule.OnErrorSignaled(Object sender, ErrorSignalEventArgs args)
   at Elmah.ErrorSignalEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, ErrorSignalEventArgs args)
   at Elmah.ErrorSignal.Raise(Exception e, HttpContext context)
   at Elmah.ErrorSignal.Raise(Exception e)
   at Ideal.API.Filters.UnhandledExceptionFilter.OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context) in C:\Repositories\edgemvc-ideal\Ideal.API\Filters\HandleErrorActionFilter.cs:line 10
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute.OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I have tried several versions of the email

```
<elmah>
    <errorMail 
      from="from" 
      to="to" 
      subject="subject" 
      async="true|false" 
      smtpPort="587|0" 
      smtpServer="smtpServer" 
      userName="userName" 
      password="password"
      useSsl="true|false"/>
  </elmah>
```

Here's what I get from google :(
[image]

Comment: I created a project from scratch and have no issues with this code, I'm wondering if there is some config setting that would cause this error.

Comment: You should probably paste your entire web.config here for anyone to be able to help. Also, you could try to validate your ELMAH config using the ELMAH Configuration Validator: https://elmah.io/tools/configvalidator

Answer (score 0):

What is null here? Based on the information provided it seems that there is no httpcontext when the above code is being executed.